Can Logical Proofs Predict Outcomes in Dynamic Systems?
In a Set Theory and Logic course I’m taking, we use the pigeonhole principle (PHP) to determine whether a function is onto or to establish properties like bijectivity. I am curious—can the PHP, through logical reasoning, be used to prove that a dynamic system with varied initial states will reach a limited set of outcomes?
For example, could the PHP show that a finite set of sine functions will map onto a constrained domain, even if some functions overlap in the same region? I am trying to understand if there are scenarios where logical principles like the PHP can help determine that such systems converge to a particular domain of outcomes, even showing that the domain isn’t unique.
I understand that dynamic systems are typically analyzed through differential equations. However, I’m interested in whether logical proofs could provide insights or guarantees about the possible outcomes of these systems. Are there examples or theorems in set theory that use concepts like the PHP to analyze or constrain the behavior of dynamic systems?
Based on these thoughts, I did some research and came across hybrid systems that combine logical proofs with differential equations, such as the tool KeYmaera X (https://www.keymaerax.org/) for analyzing self-driving cars or autonomous robots. However, these tools seem to focus primarily on such types of systems. Is there a reason why this approach isn’t commonly applied to other dynamic systems, like cell development, crystal formation, or chemical reactions? Additionally could such analyses be handled purely with logical proofs, without the need for differential equations?
